# Alamofire JSON response not usable by Hyperoslo Sync

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm using https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync and Alamofire to make a Get request to an api. This code is supposed to then be store in Core Data through Sync. The code that I have is below.

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, url + "users/getOwnUser", headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):


                let user = data.valueForKey("user")!
                let kk = [user]
                print(kk)

                Sync.changes(kk, inEntityNamed: "User", dataStack: self.dataStack, completion: { (response ) -> Void in
                    print("USER \(response)")
                })
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

The response from the print at print(kk) is

```
[{
    challenges = "<null>";
    created = "<null>";
    credentials = "<null>";
    email = "henry@hardy.com";
    emailVerified = "<null>";
    id = 6;
    lastUpdated = "2016-01-04T01:53:22.000Z";
    "phone_number" = "<null>";
    pin = "<null>";
    "pin_status" = "<null>";
    "push_options" = 0;
    "push_toggle" = 0;
    "push_token" = "<null>";
    realm = "<null>";
    status = "<null>";
    username = henryhardy;
    verificationToken = "<null>";
}]
```

which seems to have the same structure as the example provided by the creators here.

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Shawn Merrill",
    "email": "shawn@ovium.com",
    "created_at": "2014-02-14T04:30:10+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-02-17T10:01:12+00:00",
    "notes": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "text": "Shawn Merril's diary, episode 1",
        "created_at": "2014-03-11T19:11:00+00:00",
        "updated_at": "2014-04-18T22:01:00+00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

minus the semicolons vs the commas. Does anyone have any experience getting alamofire and sync to play nice? There appears to be a few people around who are experiencing this issue. Thanks!

EDIT: The response that the Sync.changes function is that it is nil.

Comment: There's an example of Sync with Alamofire.

https://github.com/3lvis/SyncAppNetDemo

Comment: Curious to know how you got on with this? I'm running into the exact same problem and haven't found any solutions. The 'id' of the object syncs fine but other int properties appear as nil if they come from the server with an underscore, eg 'correlation_id'. Boolean values as well sync as either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This framework has been deprecated, but here is a link to a repo that has an example of how it's done - https://github.com/3lvis/AppNetDemo - Thank you to 3lvis for the pointers.